# create page using different Master pages in Sharepoint 2010

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2010, master-pages

I want to have multiple customized master pages in my sharepoint 2010 sites and I want to create some pages using this different master pages. Hoiw I can do this?

When I create a page using sharepoint it use default master page but I want to have multiple master pages with different place holder.

How I can do this?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do this with Masterpages. You are looking at using page layouts. For that you need to enable the publishing feature.

First enable the Site collection publishing infrastructure feature
and the the web publishing feature.

After this you can then create your page layouts. Page layouts are templates which can be used to render the properties of the page as you which, include webparts zones, or any other custom control as you wish.

Read more about page layouts here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms544928(v=office.14).aspx

Answer (score 1):

The masterpage is not managed on page level, therefor you cannot do this, unless you make a flexible masterpage that renders differently based on the properties of the page.

Answer (score 1):

Choose Master page via the web interface is not possible. If you can use Sharepoint Server Pag layots, But if you use the Foundation there is no such system. There is an opportunity to use the Web part Pages template.

http://www.dontpapanic.com/blog/?p=58